# How to remove certain file from a list in .pro file?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

When compiling **Project 1** a bunch of object files including the `main.o` are put into buildfolder.

Now I like to use these object files in **Project 2** like a library, so what you can do is add all files manually to the the LIBS assignment by

```
//project2.pro
LIBS += $$buildfolderProject1/compressedair.o \
        $$buildfolderProject1/connectca.o \
        $$buildfolderProject1/controlpanelca.o \
        $$buildfolderProject1/compressedair.o \
        $$buildfolderProject1/moc_compressedair.o \
        $$buildfolderProject1/moc_controlpanelca.o \
        $$buildfolderProject1/moc_screenca.o \
        $$buildfolderProject1/qrc_resources.o \
        $$buildfolderProject1/screenca.o
```

A more convenient way would be like this:

```
//project2.pro
LIBS += $$buildfolderProject1/*.o
```

But as the buildfolderProject1 also contains the `main.o` of Project1 you get an error when compiling (multiple definition of main).

So I tried removing `main.o` by using:

```
LIBS -= $$buildfolderProject1/main.o
```

But that does not work with the `LIBS += $$buildfolderProject1/*.o` method.

Comment: Why do you have the not-shared `main.cpp` in the same directory as the files to be shared between projects? (Not that I'm endorsing this approach. It feels fragile.)

Comment: Sure, keeping the not-shared object files in a separate directory would be one approach. But I would be interested how to remove a certain file from the $$buildfolderProject1/*.o structure.
I use the term structure because I dont know how qmake handle this.
I think the LIBS -= substracts a certain string from a list but does not affect $$buildfolderProject1/*.o structure.

Comment: I suggest you move all the files that are mutual to both projects into a library (shared/static) then compile both of these projects by linking to the new library that you created. Much better and cleaner solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to remove a certain file from list. For explanation: 
NOT WORKING:

```
//project2.pro
LIBS += $$buildfolderProject1/*.o
LIBS -= LIBS -= $$buildfolderProject1/main.o
```

WORKING:

```
//project2.pro
myObjectFileList = $$files($$buildfolderProject1/*.o) 
myObjectFileList-= $$buildfolderProject1/main.o

LIBS += myObjectFileList
```

I do not understand totally, but somehow it hast got something to do that $$files returns an editable file list which can be edited in the .pro file.
And in the NOT WORKING Code compiling gets error because qmake extracts all .o files directly without the possibility of editing the list.

In the qmake documentation I found that the qmake built-in $$files function is a replace function.